# DNSCrypt not working - server certificate possibly expired

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, certificate

I have been using DNSCrypt for a few days (used this guide to install dominustemporis.com/2014/05/dnscrypt-on-windows-update/) and it has been working fine for a few days. Today I switched on my laptop and I couldn't connect to any website, so I ran a check on DNSCrypt-proxy and it said "This certificate has expired" (see pic below)

[image]

I switched DNSCrypt off for now by restoring the DNS server from 127.0.0.1 (which is what DNSCrypt proxies through) back to my ISPs DNS, but I would like to know how to be able to use DNSCrypt again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server certificate was actually the culprit (obviously), I uninstalled the DNSCrypt service and reinstalled it with a different, working OpenNIC DNS server address and it works fine now.

Just for reference, this is the server I switched to

```
dnscrypt-proxy.exe --resolver-name=dnscrypt.eu-dk
```